(De)activate validation temporarily or as required
I have a simple Avalonia UI Testapp with MVVM using DataAnnotations for validation.
I defined this property in my ViewModel:
        [Reactive]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

I have bound a TextBox to this property:
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />

So far, so good. It works as expected. However, the problem is that the error message "The Name field is required" is displayed immediately when the view is displayed. The user doesn't even have the opportunity to make an input.
I would like the error message to be displayed only after the user has clicked on the OK button.
Is there an easy, smart way to disable the validation or the display of the validation result until a specific action (like clicking the OK button) is performed?
I haven't been able to find a method to deactivate the error message display in the TextBox or to conditionally prevent the validation in the ViewModel.
